# Multiple tests with "starts with"

Tags: symfony, twig

I try to use a "starts with" in my template twig for test multiple string like this exemple :

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') starts with 'library_' or 'buy_' %}active{% endif %}
```

but the IF it's every time valid and return my string "active".

I verify in the Twig doc but is not specified that could you use multiple test with "Starts With"

Do you have any idea for me ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the solution is simple...

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') starts with 'library' or app.request.get('_route') starts with 'buy_' %}active{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer, this will mark this question as resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer